# Putting output from Postgres \i input to a file?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Quick question (I hope!): if I use \i to feed an input file into psql, can I get the output from the queries to be saved into a file? If so, how? Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Based on the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html), the `\o` is for directing output to a file.

Comment: This doesn't show the \echo that are in my input file but it does grab everything else. Maybe someone else knows why, but this is good enough for now. I should've figured \o would be the way to do it! Thanks again.

Comment: The [solution I proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939329/putting-output-from-postgres-i-input-to-a-file/3939359#3939359) will include `\echo` output :-).

Answer (score 9):

Using `\o`, as recommended by others, is a good solution.  Just for fun, though, another way to do this would be to pipe the input file to `psql` from the command line,  rather than using the `\i` command.  Then you could re-direct the output to another file.  For example:

```
psql < input.sql > output.txt
```

This has some interesting side effects.  For example, if you have timing turned on (`\timing on`), then using `\o` would *not* cause the timing results to be piped to the output file, but re-direction would.  Same thing with `\echo` statements.

Answer (score 7):

Sure can:

```
dbname=> \o /home/outputfile.csv
dbname=> select * from table;
dbname=> \q
```

Output will be streamed to the file.  Or

```
dbname=> \o
```

To stop streaming to file.