# psql - save results of command to a file

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm using psql's `\dt` to list all tables in a database and I need to save the results.

What is the syntax to export the results of a psql command to a file?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939329/putting-output-from-postgres-i-input-to-a-file.

Answer (score 694, accepted):

From psql's help (`\?`):

> \o [FILE]      send all query results to file or |pipe

The sequence of commands will look like this:

```
[wist@scifres ~]$ psql db
Welcome to psql 8.3.6, the PostgreSQL interactive terminal

db=>\o out.txt
db=>\dt
```

Then any db operation output will be written to out.txt.
Enter '\o' to revert the output back to console.

```
db=>\o
```

Comment: do i call this prior to the \dt, or in combination? please include syntax thanks.

Comment: Typing `\o` again turns it off.

Comment: Sadly, the output of `\?` does not go to the file. :(

Comment: for your kind perusual permission denied says try to run psql as administrator

Comment: (windows) worked only as admin and filespec without path.
File ended up in C:\windows\system32.
Ugh

Comment: Yes, `\o queries-output.txt` redirects all the subsequent commands o/p to file named `queries-output.txt` and typing `\o` (on **psql** prompt again) reverts this redirection behavior.

Comment: @blitzen9872 Yes, same here. I used `psql -c '\?' > psql_help.yml` to have the output of `\?` inside the file psql_help.yml

Comment: `psql -af file.sql > file.out` for getting input from a sql file and -a to show commands in output too. redirect all to file.out

Answer (score 128):

The psql `\o` command was already described by jhwist.

An alternative approach is using the `COPY TO` command to write directly to a file on the server. This has the advantage that it's dumped in an easy-to-parse format of your choice -- rather than psql's tabulated format. It's also very easy to import to another table/database using `COPY FROM`.

NB! This requires `superuser` or `pg_write_server_files` privileges and will write to a file *on the server*.

Example: `COPY (SELECT foo, bar FROM baz) TO '/tmp/query.csv' (format csv, delimiter ';')`

Creates a CSV file with ';' as the field separator.

As always, [see the documentation for details](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

Comment: I agree @helvete, the approach presented here provides more power for the user to configure output in a more customizing way

Comment: Note! (in 12.12) I get this error message:  "must be superuser or a member of the pg_write_server_files role to COPY to a file".  But \copy (shown below) works.

Comment: @TimV Maybe you missed it, but my answer already stated that: "NB! This requires superuser privileges"

Comment: @intgr thanks and sorry yes I did miss it (dozy old git that I am!) though I guess pg_write_server_files might be a useful role for some.

Comment: If you change your psql settings with `pset format csv` then it will write the output as a CSV. One advantage is that `\o` in psql writes to your local system, rather than the server which is probably where you want the file.

Answer (score 68):

Use o parameter of pgsql command.

> -o, --output=FILENAME    send query results to file (or |pipe)

```
psql -d DatabaseName -U UserName -c "SELECT * FROM TABLE" -o /root/Desktop/file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, was looking for a version that could be sent from CL.

Comment: I needed to add `-h localhost` and do `read PGPASSWORD` before hand to avoid password prompts (as I was looping over a list of table names)

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion

Answer (score 36):

`\copy` which is a postgres command can work for any user. Don't know if it works for \dt or not, but general syntax is reproduced from the following link [Postgres SQL copy syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html)

```
\copy (select * from tempTable limit 100) to 'filenameinquotes' with header delimiter as ','
```

The above will save the output of the select query in the filename provided as a csv file

EDIT:

For my psql server the following command works *this is an older version v8.5*

```
copy (select * from table1) to 'full_path_filename' csv header;
```

Comment: Very handy, thanks. But the 'copy' in '... copy to ...' isn't required - in fact on the recent versions it causes the command to fail.

Comment: Tom, I think it was a typo. Edited the post with the one that works on my installation pgsql 8.5ver

Comment: Just a quick note to anyone attempting to paste in a multi-line statement after \copy and getting confusing syntax errors, as I just did. You need to continue on the same line as \copy.

Comment: Is there a way to turn the \copy off? I found that if I run a statement like in your example, and then I run, for example, select * from users; that it will append the results to the most-recent file I specified instead of outputting to the screen. Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

Use the below query to store the result in a CSV file

```
\copy (your query) to 'file path' csv header;
```

Example

```
\copy (select name,date_order from purchase_order) to '/home/ankit/Desktop/result.csv' csv header;
```

Answer (score 7):

If you got the following error

```
ufgtoolspg=> COPY (SELECT foo, bar FROM baz) TO '/tmp/query.csv' (format csv, delimiter ';');
ERROR:  must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

you can run it in this way:

```
psql somepsqllink_or_credentials -c "COPY (SELECT foo, bar FROM baz) TO STDOUT (format csv, delimiter ';')"  > baz.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

```
COPY tablename TO '/tmp/output.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

this command is used to store the entire table as csv

Comment: In postgres COPY is better replaced by \COPY to avoid need of db admin.
In windows this puts the file in C:\tmp

Answer (score 1):

I assume that there exist some internal psql command for this, but you could also run the `script` command from [util-linux-ng](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux-ng) package:

> DESCRIPTION
>        Script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Approach for docker

via psql command

```
 docker exec -i %containerid% psql -U %user% -c '\dt' > tables.txt
```

or query from sql file

```
docker exec -i %containerid% psql -U %user% < file.sql > data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach **will work with any psql command from the simplest to the most complex** without requiring any changes or adjustments to the original command.

**NOTE:** For Linux servers.

---

- Save the contents of your command to a file

MODEL

```
read -r -d '' FILE_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
[COMMAND_CONTENT]

HEREDOC
echo -n "$FILE_CONTENT" > sqlcmd
```

EXAMPLE

```
read -r -d '' FILE_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
DO $f$
declare
    curid INT := 0;
    vdata BYTEA;
    badid VARCHAR;
    loc VARCHAR;
begin
FOR badid IN SELECT some_field FROM public.some_base LOOP
    begin
    select 'ctid - '||ctid||'pagenumber - '||(ctid::text::point) [0]::bigint
        into loc
        from public.some_base where some_field = badid;
        SELECT file||' '
        INTO vdata
        FROM public.some_base where some_field = badid;
    exception
        when others then
        raise notice 'Block/PageNumber - % ',loc;
            raise notice 'Corrupted id - % ', badid;
            --return;
    end;
end loop;
end;
$f$;

HEREDOC
echo -n "$FILE_CONTENT" > sqlcmd
```

- Run the command

MODEL

`sudo -u postgres psql [some_db] -c "$(cat sqlcmd)" >>sqlop 2>&1`

EXAMPLE

`sudo -u postgres psql some_db -c "$(cat sqlcmd)" >>sqlop 2>&1`

- View/track your command output

`cat sqlop`

Done! Thanks! **=D**