# How to loop a postgresql query over a list of `where` conditions

Tags: database, postgresql, loops

''m using postgresql 9.5.

For one id I can query as follows:

`select a,b from mytable where id = '1234' order by a,b;`

Q1.
I have 50 unique id's of interest in a txt file. How do I run ^ query on all those 50 id's in one go?

(Overall there are about 100000 records in the `mytable`  )

Q2.
If possible I'd also like to save the results recursively to different text files.

For 1 file I can do

```
COPY "select a,b from mytable where id = '1234' order by a,b;" TO STDOUT CSVHEADER > '/tmp/1234.csv'
```

Ref:  [psql - save results of command to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331320/psql-save-results-of-command-to-a-file/5331571)
[Save PL/pgSQL output from PostgreSQL to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file)

Extra Info : 
I'm querying from my local machine.
The postgres is installed on AWS.  (I have read access to the db).

Comment: something like? `select a,b from mytable where id in (select id from table_created_with_50_other_ids) order by a,b;`

Comment: ok thanks. this sounds like a good starting point. I must create a new table and load these 50 ids's into it and follow your tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import this text file of yours containing the ids into a temporary table and use it as a filter in a `IN` clause.

Consider a file containing these ids ...

```
1
3
```

.. and this table structure and data sample ...

```
CREATE TABLE t (id SERIAL, val TEXT);
INSERT INTO t (val) VALUES ('foo'),('bar'),('foo2'),('bar2');

SELECT * FROM t;
 id | val  
----+------
  1 | foo
  2 | bar
  3 | foo2
  4 | bar2
```

Import the ids into a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (id INT);
COPY tmp FROM '/tmp/ids.csv';
```

And use it in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp);
 id | val  
----+------
  1 | foo
  3 | foo2
(2 Zeilen)
```

Or in your export using `COPY`:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM t WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp)) TO ... ;
```